# Could someone explain what I am missing in regard to this Wronskian?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Wronskian of $f$ and $g$ is $t^2e^t$. If $f(t)=t$ what is $g$? Obviously, this reduces to the linear ODE 
$$g' + \dfrac1t g = t^2e^t$$ 
However, by tabular integration I arrive at a RHS of $e^tt^2 - 2te^t + 2e^t + c$.
But, the text asserts that this is equal to $te^t +ct$. How can the middle two terms collapse if the first one is multiplied by $t$ and second is not? That is, how is it that $t^2e^t - 2te^t + 2e^t = t^2e^t$?

Would someone please explain this to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMo the differential equation is $$tg'-g=t^2e^t$$ Where did you get that division by $\;t\;$ from?

Comment: Correct, divide through now by t. This gives an integrating factor of e^(int(1/t)) = t

Comment: Even dividing by $\;t\;$ we get $$g'-\frac1tg=te^t$$Observe the sign in the left side and the exponent of $\;t\;$ in the right one.

Comment: Hi, court, welcome on math.SE! I LaTeXed your equations and formulae. Please, have a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and learn how to do it! :)

Comment: Will do. I know I need to learn the formatting. I'll make sure the next post is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$fg'-f'g=t^2e^t\;\;\wedge\;\;f(t)=t\;\implies\;tg'-g=t^2e^t\ldots$$

So that we indeed get $\;g(t)=te^t+ct\;$ , because

$$tg'-g=t(e^t+te^t+c)-te^t-ct=t^2e^t\ldots$$

Comment: I don't understand that last line.

Comment: Sorry but one does not usually solve an ODE by checking that some function fallen from the sky solves it... I am sure you can reformulate.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to figure out why -2t * e^t + 2*e^t = 0

Comment: I know it doesn't, @Did . Did you read the question? The OP says *that* is the answer but he can't understand why, so I corrected (I think...) his Wronskian and showed how what he says his text says is correct...

Comment: And I'm trying to understand why would you try such a hopeless thing, @court, and what that has to do with your question or with my answer...

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for your help. I just typed that out of frustration. But, see I don't understand how they are doing away with those two terms. I see they are of opposite sign but one is multiplied by t and the other isn't so how do you guys collapse them?

Comment: Now I'm confused, @court : are you asking about the solution of the differential equation? Because I was under the impression, by your question, that you could do that but you couldn't understand how the solution is what it is since you had, as I showed, the wrong differential equation as your Wronskian was wrong....

Comment: @ DonAntonio, do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: @Court, can you understand how, if $\;g(t)=te^t+ct\;$ , we get  what I wrote in my answer's last line?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that after the integration and BEFORE we divide through by t to isolate g that we get the following... t^2*e^t - 2t*e^t + 2e^t + C?

Comment: @DonAntonio I *think* (but this is only a guess) that what the OP is really after is a reason why $tg'(t)-g(t)=t^2e^t$ is solved by $g(t)=te^t+ct$.

Comment: Ok @court , so it seems to be you've some doubts about the solution of the linear  diff. equation. You need the integration factor

$$e^{-\int\frac{dt}t}dt= e^{-\log t}dt=\frac1t$$

and the solution thus is

$$g(t)= t\left(\int \frac1tte^t\,dt+c\right)=t\int e^tdt+tc=te^t+tx\ldots$$

Comment: Yes @did, it looks like that. One must know some basics about linear differential equations to approach these problems. It really is pretty basic stuff. Hopefully now it's clearer.

Comment: "One must know some basics"... Perhaps, but very basics: transform the ODE into $e^t=g'(t)/t-g(t)/t^2=(g(t)/t)'$ and integrate both sides.

Comment: Well, that's the basic idea of "integrating factor"...:)

Comment: Thank you, DonAntonio. I really appreciate it.